# Two sorted subqueries into one result

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

So I have two subqueries that return the same columns from the same table

Query #1:

```
SELECT E.Id,E.Title,E.LocationId,P.LocationId,E.DepartmentId,P.DepartmentId,E.DateCreated,E.IsActive,E.IsHotJob,E.RequisitionId,E.RequisitionIdString,E.RewardSettingId,E.EmploymentOpportunityStatusId 
FROM EmploymentOpportunities E, Profiles P
WHERE E.EmploymentOpportunityStatusId = 9 AND E.IsActive = 1 AND E.IsHotjob = 1  
     AND P.Id = 'C5F07EBB-CE81-4133-A462-241A5F84D418' AND (P.DepartmentId != E.DepartmentId AND P.LocationId != E.LocationId)
ORDER BY E.DateCreated DESC
```

Query #2:

```
SELECT E.Id,E.Title,E.LocationId,P.LocationId,E.DepartmentId,P.DepartmentId,E.DateCreated,E.IsActive,E.IsHotJob,E.RequisitionId,E.RequisitionIdString,E.RewardSettingId,E.EmploymentOpportunityStatusId 
FROM EmploymentOpportunities E, Profiles P
WHERE E.EmploymentOpportunityStatusId = 9 AND E.IsActive = 1 AND E.IsHotjob = 0 AND 
      P.Id = 'C5F07EBB-CE81-4133-A462-241A5F84D418' AND (P.DepartmentId = E.DepartmentId OR P.LocationId = E.LocationId)
ORDER BY E.DateCreated DESC
```

I want this two queries combines into one but preserve the order they have, so  somehow stack Query #1 onto Query #2.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 1 SetNumber, E.Id,E.Title,E.LocationId,P.LocationId,E.DepartmentId,
  P.DepartmentId,E.DateCreated,E.IsActive,E.IsHotJob,E.RequisitionId,
  E.RequisitionIdString,E.RewardSettingId,E.EmploymentOpportunityStatusId
FROM EmploymentOpportunities E, Profiles P
WHERE E.EmploymentOpportunityStatusId = 9 AND E.IsActive = 1 
  AND E.IsHotjob = 1 P.Id = 'C5F07EBB-CE81-4133-A462-241A5F84D418' 
  AND (P.DepartmentId != E.DepartmentId AND P.LocationId != E.LocationId)

union all

SELECT 2, E.Id,E.Title,E.LocationId,P.LocationId,E.DepartmentId,P.DepartmentId,
  E.DateCreated,E.IsActive,E.IsHotJob,E.RequisitionId,E.RequisitionIdString,
  E.RewardSettingId,E.EmploymentOpportunityStatusId
FROM EmploymentOpportunities E, Profiles P
WHERE E.EmploymentOpportunityStatusId = 9 AND E.IsActive = 1 
  AND E.IsHotjob = 0 AND P.Id = 'C5F07EBB-CE81-4133-A462-241A5F84D418' 
  AND (P.DepartmentId = E.DepartmentId OR P.LocationId = E.LocationId)

ORDER BY SetNumber, DateCreated desc
```

Comment: great. this is what I was looking for. you are missing an AND in your sixth line. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Just use `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    Your Query1

    UNION ALL      // do not use order by here

    Your Query2 
) AS someName
ORDER BY yourColumn DESC
```

You can also use `UNION` -  but it will filter out duplicates if any.

Comment: It will mix the results. Not what I need